# Apply VBA macro to different pages in Visio

Tags: vba, visio

At the moment, I have a Visio file that hasa network zoning diagram (Page 1) where a user can put shaped in different zones. One can run a VB macro over that page, which will collect all kinds of data that is specific to those shapes and flows and exports it to a Word file for further reporting. That's all good and work as expected.

However, the networking zoning is different on for instance cloud. So, I want to make another page (Page 2) in the same file, that has more cloud (GCP, AWS) oriented zoning details (VPC etc.). And I want to run the same macros over that Page (2) to export the details to a word file.

PROBLEM: How and where should I tell the macro which Page it should get the data from in order to run the output. I have been playing with things like "Set vsoPage = ActiveWindow.Page" and have that executed before the macro collects all the meta information of the shapes

My hope was, based on the MS Visio page, that the macro would grab the shapes from the page that would have been active.

But no, it just spits out stuff on Page 1. And not Page 2 (although active).

Just wondering if: 
- this is the right line of code to use? 
- is the location correct?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

More likely to be:

Set vsoPage = ActivePage

Comment: Must be more page references somewhere then.

Comment: Your code must be using Visio.ActiveDocument.Pages(1) somewhere, instead of vsoPage. Maybe it uses vsoPage sometimes, but it doesn't make sense that you should have to move the page you want to be the first page. In the long run, this will certainly cause a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how and when your macro works, but here's some snippets that might help:

```
'// Get the active page:
Dim visPg as Visio.Page
Set visPg = Visio.ActivePage
If Not(visPg Is Nothing) Then
    ...
End If

'// Here we'll be really picky about the active window, this is 
'// probably overkill, but Visio can have several different types
'// of active windows:
Dim visPg as Visio.Page
Dim visWin As Visio.Window
Set visWin = Visio.ActiveWindow
If (visWin .Type = Visio.VisWinTypes.visDrawing) Then
    If (visWin .SubType = Visio.VisWinTypes.visPageWin) Then
        '// The active window is a drawing page window, and not
        '// a master-editing window, nor a group-editing window:
        Set visPg = visWin.Page
        '//...do stuff with visPg
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Sweet. I'll give this a crack. Thanks heaps

Comment: Nah, didn't work either. I think i need something like a pop up that will ask what page the macro needs to be applied to and then take that user input into the macro and run it. Not sure who to do that. Have been looking on the interweb. Haven't been able to find anything yet.

Comment: Well, i found a work around with is actually acceptable. I figured that if you have, say, 3 pages with diagrams on it. And I want to run the macro on the 2nd page. I just re-order the pages and make the 2nd page, the 1st page. The macro doesn't care. And thus runs it on that page. And when i want to run it on page 3, same thing: move it to the front of the pages/tabs and bob's my uncle. Not super elegant, but it works for me